# Opening URL using an ImageButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, click, imagebutton

using asp.net | C#

I want my ImageButton to open a URL when I click it. I finally have my Image loading and it clicks but when I click it nothing happens. Here is the code I have so far:

***aspx page***

```
   <asp:ImageButton ID="Button1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/button.gif" 
    onclick="Open_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
```

***aspx.cs page***

```
    protected void Open_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.website.com");
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do a redirect, not start a process.  Try this:

```
protected void Open_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://www.website.com");
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Additionally, you could just set the PostBackUrl attribute on the control and have no need for a server side event.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on the client-side:

This will open in another window:

```
<asp:ImageButton OnClientClick="window.open('/xxx/xxx.aspx');
```

OR this will open in same window, javascript needs to return false so server code won't run:

```
    <script>
        function ReDirect() {
            location.href = '/xxx/xxx.aspx';
            return false;
        }
    </script>

asp:ImageButton OnClientClick="javascript:return(ReDirect());" />
```